# SpringBoot - @Value is not working during JUnit Test for custom spring config location

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot

@Value is not working during JUnit Test when the **application.yml** is in another location.

FooServiceTest

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
    public class FooServiceTest {
```

EmailService in other module

```
public class EmailService {

    @Value("${aws.credentials.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
```

application.yml

```
aws:
  credentials:
    accessKey: XXXXXXXX
    secretKey: ZXXXXXXXXX
```

But I got:

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'aws.credentials.accessKey' in string value "${aws.credentials.accessKey}"
```

Even I added

```
-Dspring_config_location=/home/foo/other/location/config/
```

Comment: tell us about your AppConfig class

Comment: and remember to place application.yml in test/src/resources

Comment: the application.yml is not inside the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Standard Spring Boot locations**

If you want spring-boot's `application.properties` to be loaded, you should launch the unit test with Spring Boot (using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
public class FooServiceTest {
    @Test
    public void test...        
}
```

The `application.yml` should be under `/config` or `root` in the classpath.

See [Spring Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files):

> SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties
>   files in the following locations and add them to the Spring
>   Environment:
>
> - A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
> - The current directory
> - **A classpath /config package**
> - **The classpath root**

**Specify additional locations (exemple when executed from unit tests)**

Normally, you could have used `PropertySource`, however even though it allows to load configuration files from other locations, it will not work for injected (`@Value`) properties.

You may however specify the `spring.config.location` environment variable in a static bloc:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { AppConfig.class })
public class FooServiceTest {
    static {
        //if the file is NOT in the classpath
        System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "file:///path/to/application.yml");

        //if the file is in the classpath
        //System.setProperty("spring.config.location", "classpath:/path/in/classpath/application.yml");
    }

    @Test
    public void test...
}
```

**Run tests from Gradle**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23367507/how-to-pass-system-property-to-gradle-task) you may do this:

```
$ gradle test -Dspring.config.location=file:///path/to/application.yaml
```

Or

```
$ SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:///path/to/application.yaml gradle test
```

Or add a task to define the systemProperty:

```
task extconfig {
    run { systemProperty "spring.config.location", "file:///path/to/application.yaml" }
}

test.mustRunAfter extconfig
```

Comment: I dont use external jar, I would like to use external application.properties

Comment: The second part of my answer should help solve this using any path you wish, in a static bloc

Comment: Still not working even using the static block, have you tried to use this with gradle?

Comment: I updated the static bloc to specify a file outside of classpath (using "file://" + path structure)

Answer (score 0):

if it externalized properties and want to include in runtime via command line

when you run include **--spring.config.location=file:///location/application.yml**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-change-the-location-of-external-properties

Comment: should be --spring.config.location

Answer (score 0):

Using constructor injection makes it easy to create immutable services and enables to test without SpringContext:

```
public class EmailService {

    private final String accessKey;`enter code here`

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(@Value("${aws.credentials.accessKey}") String accessKey) {
        this.accessKey = accessKey;
    }
}

public class FooTestWithoutSpringContext {

    private EmailService emailService;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        emailService = new EmailService("mockPropertyValue");
    }

    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        emailService...
    }
}
```