# Using gradle to load command line properties but cannot find method execSpec()

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to load -Dspring.profiles.active from command line properties as per [Delegate command line system properties to spring-boot-gradle-plugin runApp task #592](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592)

Part of my gradle build file is

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
apply plugin: 'docker'

bootRun {
  execSpec {
    systemProperty 'com.example.foo', 'bar'
  }
}
```

I am getting an error message

```
Could not find method execSpec() for arguments [build_48hmmm554of8gjd2p2pou6vn0$_run_closure5$_closure17@30ae2373] on task ':bootRun' of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.run.BootRunTask.
```

How do I load execSpec()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Spring Boot 2.0.0 `execSpec` should work in `bootRun`. However I ran into the same problem today. The strange thing is, it worked at one moment and stopped working some seconds later after I changed my project name.
I realised that this change triggered a Gradle refresh and somehow afterwards there were two different versions of `spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my gradle cache. On is 57 kb and the other 58 kb. I unpacked the jars, looked into the content and found out that the difference is exactly the class `org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun`, which is 3 kb in the one and 7 kb in the other version. So I guess the 57 kb version lacks `execSpec`.

Then I directly checked the Spring repository and realised that the snapshot files are from today (11/23/2017). So a new snapshot came in today and `execSpec` is gone in that version. Since your question is from October we are probably not working with the same file but you might have had the same problem. I do not really get why `execSpec`seems to come and go, but I guess this is the price of using SNAPSHOT-versions.

So there is not much that we can do about the problem than wait until the first stable build or next snaphot that contains `execSpec` again or offers another possibility of setting system variables.

Edit:
I asked the Spring-guys [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592) what happened to `execSpec`. So `bootRun` is back to being a `JavaExec`. So it is simply not possible anymore to use `execSpec` there.

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of Spring Boot, you can just omit `ExecSpec`, like so:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperty 'com.example.foo', 'bar'
}
```